# How to store API response in react without re-render?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have the following use case. I am getting array data from an API.

Sample API response : `{key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3}`

I have the following webpage (all 3 are radio buttons).

Key1

Key2

Key3

When a user clicks on above radio button, corresponding value from API response should be displayed to the right.

I was thinking of storing the API response in a ref (not using state to avoid re-renders, not using local variable to persist data between re-renders, the API response can be updated in between based on some user action). There is also a state variable that shows the value array. So, if the key1 radio button is selected, the state variable will be [value1, , ]. Could you please tell if there is some better approach than this?

Edit 1 :

> What is the goal with preventing the re-render?

The re-render need not happen when the API response is returned but only when radio button is clicked.

> Also, how do you plan to display the response data from the API without a re-render?

Radio button => linked to state value (which retrieves from ref) => re-render.
I didn't want re-render when API response is returned which could be other user actions than radio button click.

Edit 2 :

> Why not have one state object that contains all the data and links each key to it's corresponding radio-button?

The API response of key value pairs could be retrieved in between as well due to some other action (even few key value pairs can be updated in between). But only when the radio button is clicked, the value should be displayed.

Comment: What is the goal with preventing the re-render? Also, how do you plan to display the response data from the API without a re-render?

Comment: I have updated the question, hope it helps

Comment: IIUC, the response from the API contains **all** the data? If so, why not have one state object that contains all the data and links each key to it's corresponding radio-button? Let me know if that's the case, I can provide an example as an answer to your post, I'm just not sure that I understood correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking, updated the question again

Comment: Look into `shouldComponentUpdate()`. You can perform checks here to trigger or prevent a re-render.

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell why it is better than using a ref?